# Espresso how to wait for some time(1 hour)?

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing, android-espresso

In my test case I have to record for 1 hour, in robotium solo.sleep(600000) had done my work, but In espresso I am confused with IdlingResource concept. I have to start recording and wait for some time(depending on the type of test) 15mins, 60mins etc.

Equivalent code in robotium

```
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView("start_record"));
    solo.sleep(duration * 60 * 1000);
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView("stop_record"));
```

I tried to use it like this in espresso

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class AaEspressoTest {

private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.absd.rec.RecorderActivity";
private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
private Solo solo;
private static CoreRecordingTest skyroTestRunner;


private static Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

static {
    try {
        activityClass = (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Rule
public final ActivityTestRule<?> activityRule
        = new ActivityTestRule<>(activityClass);

private IntentServiceIdlingResource idlingResource;

@Before
public void registerIntentServiceIdlingResource() {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    idlingResource = new IntentServiceIdlingResource(instrumentation.getTargetContext());
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);
}

@After
public void unregisterIntentServiceIdlingResource() {
    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
}

@Test
public void testHello() throws Exception {

 onView(withId(AaEspressoTest.getId("recorderpage_record"))).perform(click());

    registerIntentServiceIdlingResource();

    onView(withId(AaEspressoTest.getId("recorderpage_stop"))).perform(click());

   }
}
```

Idling resource

```
public class IntentServiceIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
private final Context context;
private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;
public static boolean status = false;

public IntentServiceIdlingResource(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return IntentServiceIdlingResource.class.getName();
}

@Override
public boolean isIdleNow() {
    return getTimer();
}

@Override
public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;

}

private static boolean getTimer() {

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Do Nothing
            status = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {             
            status = true;
        }
    };
    return status;
}
}
```

Exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResourceTimeoutException: Wait for [com.adbs.recorder.IntentServiceIdlingResource] to become idle timed out
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need an `IdlingResource` with an `isIdleNow()` that returns `true` only if the specific amount of time has passed. To achieve that, save the start time and compare it with current time:

```
public class ElapsedTimeIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
  private final long startTime;
  private final long waitingTime;
  private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

  public ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(long waitingTime) {
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return ElapsedTimeIdlingResource.class.getName() + ":" + waitingTime;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isIdleNow() {
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    boolean idle = (elapsed >= waitingTime);
    if (idle) {
      resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
    }
    return idle;
  }

  @Override
  public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(
      ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
  }
}
```

Create and register this idling resource in your test:

```
@Test
public static void waitForOneHour() {
  long waitingTime = DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS;

  // Start
  onView(withId(AaEspressoTest.getId("recorderpage_record")))
      .perform(click());

  // Make sure Espresso does not time out
  IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(
      waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(
      waitingTime * 2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

  // Now we wait
  IdlingResource idlingResource = new ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(waitingTime);
  Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource);

  // Stop
  onView(withId(AaEspressoTest.getId("recorderpage_stop")))
      .perform(click());

  // Clean up
  Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource);
}
```

You need the `setMasterPolicyTimeout` and `setIdlingResourceTimeout` calls to make sure Espresso does not terminate the test due to time out.

Full example: https://github.com/chiuki/espresso-samples/tree/master/idling-resource-elapsed-time

Comment: This approach doesn't work if I have more then one test method and have to idle at the end of each method for a wild. I use Espresso 2.x.

Comment: what is use of `registerIdleTransitionCallback` this method and how to use it ?

Answer (score 18):

The default timeout that Espresso will wait for all registered resources to become idle is one minute.

You can change this using the [`IdlingPolicies`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingPolicies.html) class to set an explicit timeout:

```
IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: May also need `IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);` to prevent `AppNotIdleException`.

Comment: Please, where is the IdlingPolicies set?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen you can do it anywhere - in each test or in the setup method.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Before
public void registerIdlingResource() {
    IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(60 * 1000 * 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(60 * 1000 * 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    mIdlingResource = BooleanIdlingResource.getIdlingResource();
    // To prove that the test fails, omit this call:
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mIdlingResource);
}
```

I test on my project, It works.
Just setup before register idling resources.
please check:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample
and

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingPolicies

Comment: Updates the IdlingPolicy used in UiController.loopUntil to detect AppNotIdleExceptions.

Comment: Using expressions such as `60 * 1000 * 3` seems rather pointless to me, as that's what `TimeUnit` is for. Why not just `3, TimeUnit.MINUTES` instead of reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: using `IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(60 * 1000 * 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` increased the build time all of my tests in all of my android projects. I had to reset it to 30 seconds to make them build normally. Does anyone know the reason why this might have happened?