# Force Espresso not to wait for progress

Tags: android, android-espresso

By default espresso waits for the progress bar from my activity to finish loading before executing the next instructions.

I would like to force Espresso not to wait for it and execute the rest of instructions as the progress dialog is loading.

Any hits as to where I should look for that?

After some investigations I assume I must make use of the `IdlingResource` class.

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer:

> The default timeout that Espresso will wait for all registered
> resources to become idle is one minute.
>
> You can change this using the
> [`IdlingPolicies`](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/IdlingPolicies.java?r=3969fd3414842e007ce386078facd768d25caef9)
> class to set an explicit timeout:
>
> ```
> IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
> ```
>
> From: [Espresso how to wait for some time(1 hour)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155227/espresso-how-to-wait-for-some-time1-hour)

Instead of 1 hour try to set for example 1 second (I don't know if `0` is allowed).

You can also create a custom Idling Resource like it is explained here: [Espresso: Thread.sleep( );](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417954/espresso-thread-sleep)

Hope it help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answrer. Just tried to add a custom idling resource timeout of 1 second but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Could you perhaps be a little bit more specific as to where this piece of code needs to be added? I tried adding it directly into the test.

Comment: Just check the first link above - here you would find full code with this exactly line

Comment: Just did that. The code works but the wait occurs only after the progress bar finishes. What I want is to ignore the progress bar and wait for a custom amount of time...

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/FutureProcessing/AndroidEspressoIdlingResourcePlayground and ask an author how to do it - he would better know how to solve it